# Access client ip inside nextcloud docker with haproxy docker

Tags: docker, ip-address, haproxy, nextcloud, fail2ban

I have a some docker container running and i want to see the real ip address from the client on the nextcloud docker logs. But currently i only can see the ip address from the haproxy container, i already added `option forwardfor` but still it does not work.

My docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: linuxserver/mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
      - PUID=100
      - PGID=100
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=
    volumes:
      - /home/raspi/nextcloud-docker/volumen/mariadb/:/config

  app:
    image: nextcloud:apache
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /home/raspi/nextcloud-docker/volumen/nextcloud/:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
      - OVERWRITEPROTOCOL=https
    env_file:
      - db.env
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
      - default

  haproxy:
    restart: always

    image: haproxy:2.1.7
    volumes:
      - /home/raspi/nextcloud-docker/haproxy/config:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/
      - /home/raspi/nextcloud-docker/haproxy/certs/haproxy/:/usr/local/etc/ssl/
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
    depends_on:
      - app

networks:
  proxy-tier:
```

My haproxy.cfg:

```
global
        maxconn 50
        tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
        log stdout format raw local0

defaults
        log global
        mode http
        timeout tunnel 1h
        timeout http-request 1h
        timeout connect 20s
        option forwardfor
        option http-server-close

frontend https
        bind *:8080 ssl crt /usr/local/etc/ssl/website.org
        http-request redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
        default_backend nextcloud
        timeout client 1h

backend nextcloud
        server app1 app:80
        timeout server 1h
```

The nextcloud logs:

```
{"reqId":"GoyJSJ8Jl1xAUf9xARf6","level":2,"time":"2020-09-11T23:41:54+00:00","remoteAddr":"172.29.0.3","user":"--","app":"no app in context","method":"POST","url":"/login","message":"Login failed: malo (Remote IP: 172.29.0.3)","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36","version":"19.0.0.12"}
{"reqId":"A4n1pk3sU8Bsh0pkMjfB","level":2,"time":"2020-09-11T23:43:27+00:00","remoteAddr":"172.29.0.3","user":"--","app":"no app in context","method":"POST","url":"/login","message":"Login failed: malo3 (Remote IP: 172.29.0.3)","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36","version":"19.0.0.12"}
```

As you can see, in only getting the ip address from the haproxy container. I already did add
`option forwardfor` to haproxy.cfg and did add

```
  'trusted_proxies' => array('172.29.0.3'),
  'forwarded_for_headers' => array('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'),
```

and restarted but nothing worked. I need this to make fail2ban work.
What am i missing?

Comment: Have you verified that `haproxy` is setting the correct `x-forwarded-for` header (e.g., via some sort of verbose logging, or `tcpdump`, or something)? Are you certain that `172.29.0.3` is the correct address? Every time you bring up your compose stack, the haproxy container may have a different ip address.

Comment: Ok, now i did a tcpdump and if i do `tcpdump -i any -s 0 -A | grep x-forwarded-for` i get the client ip address. So the problem is inside the nextcloud container probably.

Comment: ...unless your value for `trusted_proxies` is problematic.

Comment: You are right. That was the problem! Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make the proxy-tier network static so my networks look like this:

```
networks:
  proxy-tier:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 174.20.0.0/24
```

and the app and haproxy container i had to put this:

```
    networks:
      proxy-tier:
        ipv4_address: 174.20.0.x
```

and now add the haproxy container ip address:

```
environment:
  - TRUSTED_PROXIES=174.20.0.x
```

now it works!